# Makefile: cannot create a variable with random

Tags: makefile

I need to generate a random string and save in a variable, with a Makefile.

I wrote

```bash
install:
    LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20; echo;
    echo $(LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

When I launch it with `make install`, I get

```bash
LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = echo ANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20; echo;
/bin/sh: 1: LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN: not found
d41d8cd98f00b204e980
echo
```

So

1. missing assigned value to the variable `LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`.
2. getting every time same result for `RANDOM`

I tried also

```bash
LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = echo $$RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20; echo;
echo $(LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

with same result

```bash
LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = echo $RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20; echo;
/bin/sh: 1: LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN: not found
d41d8cd98f00b204e980
echo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each line of a recipe is a shell script, run by a different shell. Your first line is syntactically incorrect. You are trying to assign a make variable in a recipe, this is not how make works. Try:

```
install:
    LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN=$$(echo $$RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20); \
    echo $$LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

`LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` is now a shell variable, it is assigned using shell syntax in the first line of the recipe but is still defined in the second line because of the line continuation (the trailing `\`). Note the use of `$$` instead of `$` to escape the first expansion by make.

If you would like `LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` to be a make variable available in all lines of all recipes then simply assign it as a real make variable and outside any recipe :

```
LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN := $(shell echo $$RANDOM | md5sum | head -c 20)

install:
    echo $(LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but, the random is not random at all. Every time the generated string is the same.

Comment: It works like a charm here. Did you copy-paste exactly (except the leading spaces that you must replace with a tab)?

Comment: Yes, I did copy-paste. Seems random not random at all...

Comment: And on the command line? What happens if you type `echo $RANDOM` on the command line?

Comment: The `RANDOM` shell variable is not standard POSIX. It is available in bash (and maybe other shells) but not in all shells. So, if the shell that make uses to run the recipes is `sh` or `dash` it is normal that the result is always the same (probably `68b329da9893e34099c7`) because `echo $RANDOM` always returns just a newline character. To check that try to add `SHELL := bash` at the beginning of your Makefile.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. Is it possible to save the variable as "global" variable available for every line of an install recipe?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
install:
    $(eval LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN := $(shell /bin/bash -c 'echo $$RANDOM' | md5sum | head -c 20; echo))
    echo $(LOCALSTORAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

- As you also noticed, you need `$$RANDOM` in order to mask the $ sign in the Makefile
- You need to run the command in a bash, because $RANDOM may not work in all shells (did not work for me, so I had to use bash)
- You need the `$(shell ...` so that the variable gets assigned the output of the command (instead of the command text itself)
- You need `$(eval ...` because the code is inside a target, and you can not define variables in targets otherwise

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but by your use of $RANDOM | md5sum it looks like you are trying to get a unique ID. Be aware that $RANDOM has a very limited range (32k), so getting duplicates will not be very improbable. To make it safer you can e.g. add the current timestamp also (echo $RANDOM.`date +%s.%N`)